# FFmpeg split video doesn't start at 0 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

When splitting video, it's not starting from the 0th second. I followed the syntax I read in many posts, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 -i 'Wildlife.wmv' '1.wmv'
ffmpeg -i 'Wildlife.wmv' -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 '1.wmv'
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i 'Wildlife.wmv'  -t 00:00:15 '1.wmv'
```

With none of the above commands I'm able to split a video from the beginning to 15 seconds.

```
ffmpeg-php version string: 0.6.0-svn
ffmpeg-php build date string: Mar  7 2013 16:54:24
libavcodec build number: 3426306
libavcodec version number: 3426306
```

@mark4o please see below output of console

```
[root@phpweb ~]# ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -ss 0 -t 15 -acodec copy -vcodec copy  1.wmv 2>&1
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, asf, from 'Wildlife.wmv':
  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    author          :
    copyright       : Â© 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
  Duration: 00:00:30.09, start: 8.000000, bitrate: 6977 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: vc1, yuv420p, 1280x720, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
File '1.wmv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, asf, to '1.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: WVC1 / 0x31435657, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=  901 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   25467kB time=15.10 bitrate=13812.4kbits/s
video:24743kB audio:366kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.423340%

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.  (Use the **{}** preformatted text button for commands and output.)

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is. What happens instead? Does the video start from another timestamp? Does it convert at all? Do you get any errors? (If you're really using version 0.6.0, then I suggest you update to a more recent one though, just in case. 0.6.0 was released in June 2010.)

Comment: @slhck above syntax give me full video instead of 15 sec video from beginning.

Comment: From your output it looks like it actually only encoded 15.10 seconds. Please try with a more recent version of FFmpeg. There's no point in trying to troubleshoot software that has had thousands of bugs fixed since then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -i Wildlife.wmv -ss 0 -t 15 -c copy 1.wmv 2>&1
```

Comment: Care to expand on how this will help?

Comment: @Ahmet Ka got error Unrecognized option 'c'

Comment: @AhmetKa not working :(

Comment: @AhmetKa which is the working version for splitting video because as far as i know it's not working on 0.6 :) , On which version you are working on??